# How do I use Change(byVal Target as Range) to check/change cell color

Tags: excel, vba, range, byval

My primary data entry is a Worksheet named "Master".  I want to check in Range A2:A1000 when a word is entered.  If it is "CBI", "Fire", "InCase" or "LEA" nothing needs to happen in Column I (Offset(0, 8)) as it already has a no-fill (Interior.ColorIndex = -4142).  But, if any other word is entered in Range A2:A1000, Column I (Offset(0, 8)) is changed to a different color (Interior.Color = RGB(255, 231, 255)).  I have selected the discrete worksheet with "Worksheet" and "Change" but cannot get the Intersect to function.  I know the code is repetitive ... I would like to use multiple arguments, e.g., "CBI", "Fire", "InCase", "LEA" ... but it crashes at the firstIf Target line.    Alternatively, a Select Case argument might be better. I have reviewed stackoverflow results on my search "run vba when cell change" and attempted to modify without success.  I have also tried several coding attempts in the lone module where I have my other Subs which run fine, but help with this would be appreciated.

```
        Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        'Change interior color in Offset cell if certain words not entered in Range A2:A1000

            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A1000")) Is Nothing Then

                If Target(Range("A2:A1000"), "CBI") > 0 Then
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
            Else
                If Target(Range("A2:A1000"), "Fire") > 0 Then
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
            Else
                If Target(Range("A2:A1000"), "InCase") > 0 Then
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
            Else
              If Target(Range("A2:A1000"), "LEA") > 0 Then
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
            Else
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 231, 255)
            End If
  
          End If

        End Sub
```

Comment: `Target(Range("A2:A1000"), "CBI")` is not valid syntax, just check the value of `Target` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Adjust Color Depending on Another Cell's Value

- This will adjust the color of a cell in column `I` depending on the value manually entered (not by formula) in column `A`. If column `A` doesn't contain a value from a list, the cell in the same row of column `I` will get colored.
- If you already have values in column `A`, you can simply select them and do a 'copy/paste', and the colors in column `I` will be updated.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const sCriteriaList As String = "CBI,Fire,InCase,LEA" ' no spaces!
    Const sfCellAddress As String = "A2"
    Const dCol As String = "I"
    Dim diColor As Long: diColor = RGB(255, 231, 255)
    
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = Range(sfCellAddress)
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = sfCell.Resize(Rows.Count - sfCell.Row + 1)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Intersect(scrg, Target)
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim sCriteria() As String: sCriteria = Split(sCriteriaList, ",")
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = Intersect(srg.EntireRow, Columns(dCol))
    
    Dim durg As Range
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To srg.Cells.Count
        If IsError(Application.Match(CStr(srg.Cells(r)), sCriteria, 0)) Then
            If durg Is Nothing Then
                Set durg = drg.Cells(r)
            Else
                Set durg = Union(durg, drg.Cells(r))
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    drg.Interior.Color = xlNone
    If Not durg Is Nothing Then
        durg.Interior.Color = diColor
    End If
 
End Sub
```

EDIT:

- Your new idea requires changes in two lines:

  ```
      Const sCriteriaList As String = "*BI,*EA,*PD,*SO,*TF" ' no spaces!

          If Application.Count(Application _
                  .Match(sCriteria, srg.Cells(r), 0)) = 0 Then
  ```

Comment: Works perfect when as the whole ActiveCell.Value the diColor results.  Can sCriteriaList be expanded to check the last 2 characters of the ActiveCell so diColor does not occur.  E.G., ```Dim catend As String ... catend = Right(ActiveCell.Value, 2)```.  So, if BI, EA, PD, SO or TF constitute catend (as in FBI, DEA, City PD, County SO, BATF), the diColor does not occur? (Had to rephrase the comment)

Comment: I've posted an edit at the bottom.

Comment: I tried ```Const sCriteriaList As String = "CBI,Fire,InCase,LEA",*BI,*EA,*PD,*SO,*TF"``` and replaced ```If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub``` with ``` If Application.Count(Appli...``` Didn't process.  I am wanting both the original ```sCriteriaList``` and your edit.  Are they as separate lines or in the same ```Const```? And, for the ```If Application``` . . . does it follow the ```Dim srg```?  Confusted . . . but really am trying to understand.

Comment: Overnight thinking . . . all the would be necessary in the ```Const sCriteriaList As String``` would be InCase and the last 2 characters.  I can eliminate CBI, Fire and LEA.  The string would only need to be comprised of ```= "InCase, *BI,*EA,*FD,*PD,*SO,*TF"``` As you see the last 2 chars are of governmentt agencies and are inherently unique so they could be added to.  I will keep trying to figure out where to put the ``` If Application.Count(Appli...``` coding, but your input is invaluble.

Comment: There's nothing to figure out: the line replaces the `If IsError... line` and add the additional strings (no spaces!) to the list. There is only one list: from double-quote to double-quote e.g. `"Fire,InCase,*BI,*EA,*PD,*SO,*TF"`.

Comment: I see.  Trying to read too much into it. Thx.

Comment: VBasic2008 ... The code to color fill ColI based on ColA works like a charm.  I have not, however, been able to figure out how to simultaneously color ColA's cell so both cells are color-filled.  Same criteria, just that on entering ColA I would like it to assume color fill also.  Can you assist?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This can so easily be done, using conditional formatting. I have created the following rule:

```
=AND(A2<>"CBI",A2<>"Fire",A2<>"InCase",A2<>"LEA")
```

And applied it on my "B" column, as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

And this is the result:

[image]